# Is glycine strong or weak field ligand? If yes, how?

Tags: coordination-compounds

The fact that it contains both oxygen and nitrogen atoms is confusing me since N is generally strong ligand field while O has a weak ligand field

Comment: A man can be a strong sword fighter if he uses his right hand, and at the same time a poor fighter with his left hand (or vice versa). Same thing here.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Except that we can’t really classify either atom as strong or weak field …